# how to fetch value of jsonArray with no field name in java?

Tags: java, json, api

I want to get JSON array value from this [link](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=bulgari&client=chrome)

jsonArray format is looks like this

```
["bulgari",["bulgaria","bulgari aqua","bulgarian","bvlgari man","bulgarian yogurt","bvlgari ring","bulgaria cup","bulgari bali","bvlgari man in black","bvlgari aqva","bvlgari omnia","bulgari hotel","bulgarian yoghurt","bvlgari pour homme","bvlgari rose","bulgaria u19","bulgaria vs kosovo","bulgaria first professional football league playoff","bulgarian journal of agricultural science","bulgaria negara miskin"],["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],[],{"google:clientdata":{"bpc":false,"tlw":false},"google:suggestrelevance":[750,601,600,566,565,564,563,562,561,560,559,558,557,556,555,554,553,552,551,550],"google:suggesttype":["QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY"],"google:verbatimrelevance":1300}]
```

I want the result is to fetch the value just like this

```
bulgaria,bulgari aqua,bulgarian,bvlgari man,bulgarian yogurt,bvlgari ring,bulgaria cup,bulgari bali,bvlgari man in black,bvlgari aqva,bvlgari omnia,bulgari hotel,bulgarian yoghurt,bvlgari pour homme,bvlgari rose,bulgaria u19,bulgaria vs kosovo,bulgaria first professional football league playoff,bulgarian journal of agricultural science,bulgaria negara miskin
```

This is what I have tried

```
String sURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=bulgari&client=chrome"; //just a string
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    // Connect to the URL using java's native library
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    request.connect();
    JSONArray values = json.getJSONArray(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject item = values.getJSONObject(i); 

    System.out.println(item);
  }
```

But the result is showing error message like this

```
cd C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testAPI; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Downloads\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.testapi.testAPI\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Downloads\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building testAPI 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ testAPI ---
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] not found.
    at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:218)
    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:405)
    at com.mycompany.testapi.testAPI.main(testAPI.java:87)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.796 s
Finished at: 2019-07-08T09:41:51+07:00
Final Memory: 7M/30M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project testAPI: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Note:
* i am using jdk 11 and netbeans IDE 11.0

Comment: You haven't added anything to the JSONArray named json, so trying to access its first member will fail.  You probably need to fill it with data from the request?

Comment: @Mark i've tried to fill it with sURL variable but now showing this error `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:161)
 at com.mycompany.testapi.testAPI.main(testAPI.java:82)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
        String sURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=bulgari&client=chrome"; //just a string
        InputStream is = new URL(sURL).openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }        
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        JSONArray myData = jsonArray.getJSONArray(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < myData.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(myData.getString(i));
        }
```

Comment: what is -1 refers to?

Comment: It just means, "read until there is no more data". You need to get the whole JSON document, not just the part you are interested in, or JSONArray won't be able to parse it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your answer is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with the JSON-P API (see ).

```
      try (var stream = new URL(sURL).openStream())
      {
         var reader = Json.createReader(stream);
         var array = reader.readArray();
         System.out.println(array.toString());
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         // log exception here
         ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
      }
```